# filtering a json file by keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Im missing something with my json file that I cant seem to figure out. I am creating a search by keyword with angular, and im using an external json file as the data. Currently, without filtering, It gives me all of the table cells, as opposed to just the ones I want.

The end result would be to have it only repeat over the subjects for each category. And for some reason its repeating over all of them for each subject, and only showing the ones i ask for. This leaves large gaps of empty cells.

html:

```
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0px;padding-top:25px;margin-top:180px;">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group" style="border-bottom:1px solid white;">
            <input ng-model="searchText" type="text" class="form-control logon-input" id="username" placeholder="Search" autofocus>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0px;">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>CONTENT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in categories | filter:searchText">
            <td>{{item.subject_1}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>SOCIAL MEDIA</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in categories | filter:searchText">
            <td>{{item.subject_2}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>SOCIAL MEDIA TRACKING</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in categories | filter:searchText">
            <td>{{item.subject_3}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>ENGAGEMENT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in categories | filter:searchText">
            <td>{{item.subject_4}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

angular:

```
    app.controller('search_ctrl', ['$scope','$http', 
     function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get('js/data.json').then(function(response){
       $scope.categories = response.data;
      });
     }]);
```

json:

```
[
{"subject_1":"Owned Content"},
{"subject_1":"Earned Content"},
{"subject_2":"Social Media Platforms"},
{"subject_2":"Facebook"},
{"subject_2":"Instagram"},
{"subject_2":"Snapchat"},
{"subject_2":"Twitter"},
{"subject_2":"Youtube"},
{"subject_2":"Radarly By Linkinfluence"},
{"subject_3":"Impressions"},
{"subject_3":"Owned Impressions"},
{"subject_3":"Earned Impressions"},
{"subject_3":"Reach"},
{"subject_3":"Owned Reach"},
{"subject_3":"Earned Reach"},
{"subject_4":"Engagement Actions"},
{"subject_4":"Engagement Rate"}

]
```

Comment: Please share jsFiddle or codepen

Comment: where is the filter code?

Comment: use `ng-if` for `ng-repeat` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is working fine in its way you need to change your code something like

from

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in categories | filter:searchText">
            <td>{{item.subject_4}}</td>
        </tr>
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in categories | filter:searchText" ng-if="item.subject_4">
            <td>{{item.subject_4}}</td>
        </tr>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf6gd1uu/)